# Issue with extending a Super class mapped with @MappedSuperClass annotation

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Hello need some help i need to use a POJO class with all the Columns defined in it and it is mapped with `@MappedSuperClass` annotation (Say class A)

Now i have a class B and which extends the Class A but now the interesting thing is i dont all the fields in this Entity class that are mentioned in Class A, i wanted to know how can i override them so that the Entity Manager doesnt reference all the columns from Class A and give me a invalid identifier exception.

I have tried

```
@AttributeOverride(name = "attributeName", column = @Column(nullable = true))
```

As well, I tried

```
@AttributeOverride(name = "attributeName", column = @Column(name = "Column_Name", insertable = false, updatable = false)).
```

I will have to extend the Class A for sure since its in a library i am using and it does a lot of work else i will have to rewrite the whole code that the library does. I cant even remove the extra columns in Class A since its being used by other Applications. Please help me out.

Comment: That's not possible

Comment: Have you ever use customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) method and used ExpressionBuilder in the method ?

Comment: Finally found a solution for it, I had to create a customizer class and implement DescriptorCustomizer Interface and in the customize method  i      public class Customizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
        descriptor.removeMappingForAttributeName("NameofAtributeinSuperClass");
        descriptor.removeMappingForAttributeName("NameofAtributeinSuperClass");
    }
}